# Visual studio block chain smart contract deployment issue

Tags: visual-studio, solidity

I am a dotnet developer want to enter into this ethereum blockchain world and also install solidity to create smart contracts and however i am expensing the following issue Deployment to **http://localhost:8001/** started!
User used for deployment: testuser User found: 0d97173dc52b4d8b2c1034228b129c6d763160eb Contract Payout created successfully at address error uploading contract Contract can be accessed here: **http://localhost:8001/contracts/Payout/error uploading contract.html** (default password: testing) Anyone please help me to resolve this , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue which could be because the used Visual Studio extension is depending on this NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/blockapps-bloc that seems to be outdated. Because, it is referencing the a GitHub source that is removed or renamed: http://github.com/blockapps/bloc

Original Steps that I follow when I faced the error is from:
[medium.com/@ConsenSys/solidity-integration-with-visual-studio-8bdab2ff8a74](http://medium.com/@ConsenSys/solidity-integration-with-visual-studio-8bdab2ff8a74) (written on Apr 1, 2016)
And they are the same also from Microsoft site: 
[visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/96221853-33c4-4531-bdd5-d2ea5acc4799](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/96221853-33c4-4531-bdd5-d2ea5acc4799)
Where the error happen when right-click on any contract and chose to deploy. By the way, it compiles successfully!

Visual Studio extension is only for 2015 (you have to install Visual Studio 2015 and it will not work with 2017). The extension could be fond at:
[marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConsenSys.Solidity](http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConsenSys.Solidity)

Answer (score 0):

Solidity extension will not work on VS2017. Open the extension and change the target in config file .

Comment: Open the VS extension and change "extension.vsixmanifest"  and replace with version below   
<InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,15.5)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,15.5)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,15.5)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />

Comment: add the details to the answer. Answers without enough details or efforts to solve the problem will be removed.